How to show project without reference in tests in SonarQube coverlet .NET test coverage?
I'm trying to add sonarqube test coverage to my project. In .NET solution I got:

ProjectA
ProjectB
ProjectC

and test projects

TestProjectForA
TestProjectForB

When I run dotnet test with Include property for all 3 projects I got final table with only ProjectA and ProjectB coverage.
I know that projectC doesn't have tests but it should show 0% in line/branch/and method coverage.
Why it's not showing in results?
